# How to place a navigationItem in Navigation Bar programmatically in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I add a NavigationBar with a NavigationBarItem in a NavigationController, such that when I push my navigationItem I should get my previous view without using Interface Builder in Objective-C

Comment: Why does not uses directly an UINavigationController?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to programmatically add a `NavigationBarItem` for the back-button. This will be automatically added to the `UINavigationBar` by the framework itself. Simply provide a value for your `title` property of your base view an you'll see a matching button in the pushed navigation view.